# How to disable animation for md-tabs in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to disable the animation for the content while tab switching. I want animation only for tabs not for the content.

I tried `md-no-ink`, but its not working for me. I tied moving the tab contents to outside `md-tabs` tags also. But this is also not working.

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-no-ink md-no-bar>
      <md-tab label="Re-Iterate Inputs" ng-if="models.length<3">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <div id="model_detail">
            <div class="jqx-table" style="margin-bottom: 20px; " >
                <div id="jqxModelParamRe"></div>
            </div>
            <h4 class="s-title">Input Parameters</h4>
            <form id="paraForm" name="paraForm">
                <div layout>
                <div flex=20 layout="column">
                    <label class="input-label">No. of Trees</label>
                    <md-input-container md-no-float>
                        <input type="number" step="1" min="1"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" ng-disabled="model.readOnlyBtn" placeholder=">0 Integer " name=nTree ng-model="model.nTree" class="input-div" required>
                            <div ng-messages="paraForm.nTree.$error" multiple md-auto-hide="false">
                              <div ng-message="required">
                                This field is required
                              </div>
                              <div ng-message="min">
                                Value should be greater than 0
                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <div flex=20 flex-offset=5 layout="column">
                    <label class="input-label">Depth of Trees</label>
                    <md-input-container md-no-float>
                        <input ng-disabled="model.readOnlyBtn" type="number" step="1" min="1"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
                  name="dTree" placeholder=">0 Integer " ng-model="model.dTree" class="input-div" required>
                        <div ng-messages="paraForm.dTree.$error" multiple md-auto-hide="false">
                          <div ng-message="required">
                            This field is required
                          </div>
                          <div ng-message="min">
                            Value should be greater than 0
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <div flex=20 flex-offset=5 layout="column">
                    <label class="input-label">Learning Rate</label>
                    <md-input-container md-no-float>
                        <input ng-disabled="model.readOnlyBtn" type="number" min=0 max=1 placeholder="from 0.0 to 1.0"
                  name="l_rate" ng-model="model.learning_rate" class="input-div" required>
                        <div ng-messages="paraForm.l_rate.$error" multiple md-auto-hide="false">
                          <div ng-message="required">
                            This field is required
                          </div>

                          <div ng-message="min">
                            Value should be greater than 0
                          </div>

                          <div ng-message="max">
                             Value should be smaller than 1
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
               </div>
               <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <md-button ng-disabled="model.readOnlyBtn" type=submit id="step-btn"
              class="build-model md-raised step-btn md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple"
              ng-click="setReIterate()">
                Build Model</md-button>
              </form>
          </div>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Set Schedule">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <div id="schedule">
            <form id="schedule_form" name="schedule_form" novalidate>
            <h2 class="img-title"><img src="img/time.png" style="margin-right:8px;">Schedule</h2>

            <p style="text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-weight: 500;
                    box-sizing: border-box;font-size:14px;padding-top:20px;">
                  Select Iteration
            </p>
            <div layout="row" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
              <div ng-repeat="i in models track by $index" layout="column" ng-class="i_class[$index]" ng-click="i_activate($index)">
                Iteration {{$index+1}}
              </div>
            </div>


            <p style="text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-weight: 500;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    font-size:14px;">
                  Deployment Options
            </p>
            <div layout="row" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
              <div ng-repeat="i in d_class track by $index" layout="column" ng-click="d_activate($index)">
                <span ng-show="$index == 0" ng-class="d_class[$index]">Continue Without Deployment</span>
                <span ng-show="$index == 1" ng-class="d_class[$index]">Deploy To Production</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="column">
            <p style="text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-weight: 500;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    font-size:14px;" ng-show="d_selected == 1">
                  Select Server
            </p>
            <div ng-show="d_selected == 1">
            <select ng-model="deploy_server" class="form-control"
                 ng-options="x.ref_key as x.ref_value for x in master_data.deploy_server" required style="width:300px;margin-bottom:40px;">
           </select>
            </div>
            </div>


            <div layout>
                <div flex=20 layout="column">
                    <label>Start Date</label>
                <md-datepicker md-placeholder="Start date" ng-model="schedule.start_date" required >
                </md-datepicker>
                </div>
                <div flex=20 layout="column">
                    <label>End Date</label>
                <md-datepicker md-placeholder="End Date" ng-model="schedule.end_date" required md-min-date="schedule.start_date">
                </md-datepicker>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" flex style="margin-top:10px;">
                <div flex=20 layout="column">
                    <label class="input-label">Frequency to Retrain </label>
                    <md-input-container>
                  <select ng-disabled="model.readOnly" ng-model="schedule.frequency" required
                       ng-options="x.ref_key as x.ref_value for x in master_data.sch_freq" required style="height: 33px;
                      width: 140px; padding-left:5px">
                 </select>
                        <div ng-messages="schedule_form.frequency.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
                        </div>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
              <div layout="column" flex=40></div>
            </div>
            <h4 class="s-title">File Settings</h4>
           <div ng-repeat="item in trainObject" class="train_setting">
            <div id="train_setting" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <div class="sep-hr"></div>
              <div layout>
                <div flex=40 layout="column">
                <div>
                    <label class="input-label">Training Folder Path</label>
                </div>
                  <div layout  id="train_folder_path">
                  <md-input-container  md-no-float flex=100>
                      <input  ng-change="changeTrainName($index)" ng-model="item.folder_path" name="item.folder_path" placeholder="Enter full file path/Select Time array options from below" class="input-div" required>
                </md-input-container>
                    </div>
              </div>
                </div>
              <div layout class="s-title" style="color:rgb(53, 151, 218); margin-bottom:20px; font-size:14px; ">Add any delimiter between the wild characters as per your file name</div>


             <div layout>
                <div flex=40 layout="column">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <label class="input-label">File Time Array</label>
                </div>
                <div layout>
                    <div flex=20>
                        <md-checkbox  ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-change="changeTimeArray('{YYYY}',item.yyyy,$index);"
                        ng-model="item.yyyy" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            YYYY
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-change="changeTimeArray('{MM}',item.mm,$index)"
                        ng-model="item.mm" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            MM
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=20>
                        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-change="changeTimeArray('{Week}',item.week,$index)" ng-model="item.week" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            Week
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-change="changeTimeArray('{DD}',item.dd,$index)"
                        ng-model="item.dd" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            DD
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-change="changeTimeArray('{Hr}',item.hr,$index)"
                        ng-model="item.hr" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            Hr
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-change="changeTimeArray('{Min}',item.min,$index)"
                        ng-model="item.min" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            Min
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>

             <div layout>
               <span style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:20px;">Select Last</span>
               <input type="number" step="1" min="1"
                      style="width: 50px;margin-right: 30px;" ng-model="item.file_range"/>
              <select ng-model="item.file_range_unit" required
                    ng-options="x.ref_key as x.ref_value for x in master_data.sch_files" required style="height: 33px;
                   width: 140px; padding-left:5px" >
              </select>
             </div>

             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="sep-hr"></div>
              <div layout style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

                  <div ng-click="addTrainObject()" flex=9>
                    <span  class="path-plus-btn" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:20px; color:rgb(53, 151, 218);">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;">Add training folder</span>
                    </span>

                  </div>

                  <div flex=20>
                    <span ng-click="deleteTrainObject()" class="path-minus-btn" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:20px; color:rgb(53, 151, 218); margin-left: 10px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span style="font-size: 14px;">Delete last training folder</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>


          <!--<hr style="width:900px;margin:20px 0px 30px 0px;">-->
            <div id="validation-folder">
            <div layout>
                <div flex=40 layout="column">
                <div>
                    <label class="input-label">Validation Folder Path  <span style="color:rgb(53, 151, 218); margin-left:20px;font-size:14px;">Only the latest file will be selected</span></label>
                </div>
                <md-input-container md-no-float>
                    <input  ng-change="changeValidName()" ng-model="schedule.valid_folder_path"  class="input-div" placeholder="Enter full file path/Select Time array options from below" required>
                   </md-input-container>
              </div>
               </div>
              <div layout class="s-title" style="color:rgb(53, 151, 218); margin-bottom: 20px;font-size:14px;">Add any delimiter between the wild characters as per your file name</div>

               <div layout>
                <div flex=40 layout="column">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <label class="input-label">File Time Array</label>
                </div>
                <div layout>
                    <div flex=20>
                        <md-checkbox ng-change="changeValidTimeArray('{YYYY}',schedule.valid_yy)" ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-model="schedule.valid_yy" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            YYYY
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-change="changeValidTimeArray('{MM}',schedule.valid_mm)" ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-model="schedule.valid_mm" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            MM
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=20>
                        <md-checkbox ng-change="changeValidTimeArray('{Week}',schedule.valid_week)" ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-model="schedule.valid_week" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            Week
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-change="changeValidTimeArray('{DD}',schedule.valid_dd)" ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-model="schedule.valid_dd" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            DD
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-change="changeValidTimeArray('{Hr}',schedule.valid_hr)" ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-model="schedule.valid_hr" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            Hr
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                    <div flex=15>
                        <md-checkbox ng-change="changeValidTimeArray('{Min}',schedule.valid_min)" ng-disabled="model.readOnly" class="md-warn" ng-model="schedule.valid_min" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
                            Min
                        </md-checkbox>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>


             </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sep-hr"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <md-button ng-click="setFinalize('schedule')" type=submit id="step-btn" class="build-model md-raised step-btn md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple">Schedule</md-button>

             </form>

             <!-- end of form -->
             </div>

        </md-content>

      </md-tab>

      <md-tab label="Skip & Finalize">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <p style="text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-weight: 500;
                  box-sizing: border-box;
                  font-size:14px;">
                Select Iteration
          </p>
          <div layout="row" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
            <div ng-repeat="i in models track by $index" layout="column" ng-class="i_class[$index]" ng-click="i_activate($index)">
              Iteration {{$index+1}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <p style="text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-weight: 500;
                  box-sizing: border-box;
                  font-size:14px;">
                Deployment Options
          </p>
          <div layout="row" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
            <div ng-repeat="i in d_class track by $index" layout="column" ng-click="d_activate($index)">
              <span ng-show="$index == 0" ng-class="d_class[$index]">Continue Without Deployment</span>
              <span ng-show="$index == 1" ng-class="d_class[$index]">Deploy To Production</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <p style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; box-sizing: border-box; font-size:14px;" ng-show="d_selected == 1">Select server</p>
          <div ng-show="d_selected == 1">
            <select ng-model="deploy_server" class="form-control" ng-options="x.ref_key as x.ref_value for x in master_data.deploy_server" required style="width:300px;margin-bottom:40px;"></select>
          </div>
          <md-button type=submit id="step-btn" class="build-model md-raised step-btn md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-click="setFinalize()">Save</md-button>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with your demo and its working with `md-no-ink`.
check my codepen

See the Pen [Material Tabs](https://codepen.io/BhavanPatel/pen/owjjdz/) by Bhavan Patel ([@BhavanPatel](https://github.com/BhavanPatel)).